# .NET Client Profile on x64

Tags: .net, installation, 64-bit, .net-client-profile

I know that the .NET Client profile [does not target x64 or ia64](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/trickster92/archive/2008/05/21/introducing-the-net-framework-client-profile.aspx). However I do not know what that means?

There are two parts that it affects

1. If I set my application to use the .NET Client Profile in VS, and it is run on x64 will it work?
2. If I set my setup project prerequisites to need the .NET Client Profile rather than the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, what will happen if it is run on x64 machine that does not have the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The client profile is just a stripped down version of the full framework designed to minimise install time if the user doesn't already have the .net framework. The client profile itself cannot be installed on an x64 machine, but your app will work fine if the full framework is installed.

Note that as of .net 4.0, the client profile will support all architectures, include x64 ([see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2009/05/27/net-framework-4-client-profile-introduction.aspx))

As far as part 2 is concerned, if the .net framework isn't installed on the PC, you will get the usual '.net framework is required for this app' dialog.

Answer (score 2):

1: in theory it should work **if** the user has *regular* .NET 3.5SP1 installed (since client-profile is 3.5SP1 specific IIRC)

2: I would expect that you get some very funky "can't run that" message (error) boxes

I would spin up an x64 VM and test it, but I'm on my laptop at the moment and it won't do that (no VT)